# How do I correctly show a proof of this implication and refute it's converse?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

If there is a valid implication between the two, show the proof. If not, refute it by giving a counter example.

1) $x+5>8$

2) $\left| x \right| >3$

$$x+5>8\Rightarrow \left| x \right| >3$$

Assuming $x+5 > 8$, I will prove $\left| x \right| >3$

1) $x+5 > 8$ is equivalent to $x > 3$

2) Squaring both sides gives us $x^2 > 9$

3) Taking the square root gives us $\sqrt { { x }^{ 2 } } >3$

4) $\sqrt { { x }^{ 2 } }$ is equivalent to $\left| x \right|$

5) So, $\sqrt { { x }^{ 2 } } >3\Rightarrow \left| x \right| >3$

6) Therefore, $x + 5 > 8\Rightarrow \left| x \right| >3$

$$\left| x \right| >3\Rightarrow x+5>8$$

$x$ could be equal to $-5$ which would negate the statement since $\left| -5 \right| >3$ is $T$; however, $-5+5>8$ is $F$

Is my proof and refutation correct? If not, how can they be improved/fixed?

Comment: It is correct, but your steps 2 through 4 are unnecessary.  You could simply note that as $x>3$, you have $x$ is positive, implying that $|x|=x$, so $|x|>3$.

Comment: How about the refutation of $\left| x \right| >3\Rightarrow x+5>8$

Was I right about how the first was correct and the second was incorrect?

Comment: Yes.  $x=-5$ is a perfectly good counterexample for exactly the reason you say.

Comment: So, all in all (besides the redundancy), my answer to the question is satisfactory? 

I'm only asking because I am trying to improve my proof writing skills and logic. I want to see if I am getting somewhere in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Your second step is not allowed and leads to the wrong conclusion.

Your first claim refers only to positive values greater than 3. Your second sentences allows the mirror values as well, which are negative, less than -3. The two are clearly not equivalent.